# C++ program not distinguishing between upper and lower case letters in OpenCV application

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm editing a relatively big OpenCV-based program written by some colleagues.
The problem I'm facing is that the program does not distinguish between upper and lower case keystrokes (i.e both keystrokes 'd' and 'D' are seen as 0x65)
My colleague told me that he solved the problem on his machine by compiling the OpenCV libraries on his machine directly from source.

I'm a newbie, but also curious why such thing would even happen and how would it be related to OpenCV installation!

I still have the problem on my machine but I have not tried reinstalling openCV.

EDIT:
OS Linux-Ubuntu 12.10 **64bit**
The letters are keystrokes from the Keyboard and they are used in a switch statement.

```
    static int process_key(struct cam_segment* cs, int key){
    int res = 0;
    double pdist;
    struct stat sb;
    char fn[4096];
    static int out_id = 0;
    fprintf( stderr, "%d\n", key&0xff );
    switch (key & 0xff) {
    case 'm':
        show_merged = !show_merged;
        res = 1;
        break;
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
        cam_id = (key & 0xff) - '1';
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'D':
        ocv_mgrid_set_distortion( cs->mg, 0 );
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'd':
        ocv_mgrid_set_distortion( cs->mg, 1 );
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'n':
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'C':
        init_calibration(cs);
        calibrate_camera_distortion(cs->mg);
        output_calibration_results(cs);
        cs->calib_mode = 1;
        res = 1;

        break;
    case 'c':
        init_calibration(cs);
        fprintf(stderr,"searching.....");
        calibrate_camera_rotation(cs->mg);
        output_calibration_results(cs);
        fprintf(stderr,"e1 %f\n",water_error(cs->mg));
        cs->calib_mode = 1;
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'M':
        init_calibration(cs);
        fprintf(stderr,"searching pricipal point.....");
        calibrate_camera_center(cs->mg);
        output_calibration_results(cs);
        cs->calib_mode = 1;
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'a':
        init_calibration(cs);
        int misscnt;
        double e,en;
        en = e = HUGE;
        misscnt = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
            e = water_error(cs->mg);
            fprintf(stderr,"e1 %f %d \n",e,misscnt);
            calibrate_camera_rotation(cs->mg);
            output_calibration_results(cs);
            en = water_error(cs->mg);
            fprintf(stderr,"en1 %f\n",en);
            if (en >= e)
                misscnt++;
            else
                misscnt = 0;
            if (misscnt > 3)
                break;
            e = water_error(cs->mg);
            fprintf(stderr,"e %f %d\n",e,misscnt);
            calibrate_coupled_focal_length(cs->mg);
            output_calibration_results(cs);
            en = water_error(cs->mg);
            fprintf(stderr,"en %f\n",en);
            if (en >= e)
                misscnt++;
            else
                misscnt = 0;
            if (misscnt > 3)
                break;
            e = water_error(cs->mg);
            if (e > 100) 
                continue;
            fprintf(stderr,"e %f %d\n",e,misscnt);
            calibrate_camera_distortion(cs->mg);
            output_calibration_results(cs);
            en = water_error(cs->mg);
            fprintf(stderr,"en %f\n",en);
            if (en >= e)
                misscnt++;
            else
                misscnt = 0;
            if (misscnt > 3)
                break;
        }
        cs->calib_mode = 1;
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'p':
        init_calibration(cs);
        calibrate_coupled_focal_length(cs->mg);
        output_calibration_results(cs);
        cs->calib_mode = 1;
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'F':
        init_calibration(cs);
        calibrate_focal_lengths(cs->mg);
        output_calibration_results(cs);
        cs->calib_mode = 1;
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 't':
        init_calibration(cs);
        calibrate_target(cs->mg);
        output_calibration_results(cs);
        cs->calib_mode = 1;
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'e':
        sprintf(fn, "%s_%03d.png",cs->inp_prefix, cs->inp_id);
        if (!(input = cvLoadImage(fn, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR))) {
            fprintf(stderr,"error calc: loading input failed\n");
        } else if (!(ocv_mgrid_set_input(cs->mg, input))) {
            fprintf(stderr,"error calc error 1\n");
        }
        pdist = water_error(cs->mg);
        fprintf(stderr,"watererror: %f\n",pdist);
        break;
    case 'N':
        res = 1;
        cs->inp_id++;
        cerr << "inp_id=" << cs->inp_id << "\n";
        break;
    case 'P':
        res = 1;
        cs->inp_id--;
        cerr << "inp_id=" << cs->inp_id << "\n";
        break;

    case 'z':
        cs->color_mode = OCV_MGRID_CMODE_THETA;
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'Z':
        cs->color_mode = OCV_MGRID_CMODE_THETA_CHECK;
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'l':
        cs->draw_legend = !(cs->draw_legend);
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'x':
        cs->color_mode = OCV_MGRID_CMODE_X;
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'y':
        cs->color_mode = OCV_MGRID_CMODE_Y;
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'X':
        cs->color_mode = OCV_MGRID_CMODE_X_CHECK;
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'Y':
        cs->color_mode = OCV_MGRID_CMODE_Y_CHECK;
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'o':
        cs->color_mode = OCV_MGRID_CMODE_NONE;
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 's':

        sprintf(fn, "input_%03d.png",out_id);
        while(stat(fn, &sb) != -1) {
            out_id++;
            sprintf(fn, "input_%03d.png",out_id);
        }
        fprintf(stderr,"saving %s \n",fn);
        cvSaveImage(fn,OCV_MGRID_GET_INPUT(cs->mg));
        break;
    case 'r':
        if (projection)
            cvResetImageROI(projection);
        if (merged_projection)
            cvResetImageROI(merged_projection);
        if (merged_grid)
            cvResetImageROI(merged_grid);
        if (output)
            cvResetImageROI(output);
        break;
    case 'R':
        reset_defaults();
        reset_trackbars();
        break;
    case 'f':
        ocv_mgrid_get_best_projection_distance(cs->mg, &pdist);
        fprintf(stderr,"best match %f\n",pdist);
        tb_pdist = (int) pdist;
        cvSetTrackbarPos("proj_distance", "tbars", tb_pdist);
        res = 1;
        break;
    case 'w':
        if (use_camera)
            if (!(ocv_ueye_whitebalance(cs->ueye)))
                return 1;
        break;
    case 'W':
        save_params(cs);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Please explain better, in what way a program does not distinguish between upper and lower case keystrokes? Where do the keystrokes come from, how are they processed, etc?

Comment: This should be related to the cvWaitKey() function, however, after checking the code (2.4.2), I don't see anything that could ignore the case. By the way, why do you mask (& 0xff) the key value ? Did you try without ? What OS ?

Comment: @kebs: the masking is just to remove any keyboard specific data in the higher bits, since there is no usefuld data there. I removed the masking and I tried but it does not work

Comment: Your code listing omits the part where you get the key from the OS or library.

Comment: A common trick to force ASCII chars to lower case is to forcefully set the 5th bit, as in `key |= 0x20;` Maybe this is what happens?

Comment: can't side your findings on win: 0x64=='d'  0x44=='D' from waitKey() here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why until now!
But i have removed the old OpenCV libraries and compiled the latest version. And now it does distinguish between the upper and lower case letters.

The new version has some subtle differences which are not necessarily good, for example  values of track bars cannot be edited by clicking on them anymore. In addition (@ kebs) the key strokes have to be masked now with 0xff now!

I don't know maybe i had a weird OpenCV version all along!